# Azure Easy API - can't find documentation for getTable('tableName').insert

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Azure Easy API on my app service. I'm experimenting a little bit and I can't find proper documentation for this stuff.

When I made a new Easy API, the comments at the top said

`// Use "request.service" to access features of your mobile service, e.g.:
//   var tables = request.service.tables;`

So I went from there to finding out I can add to any of my tables using `request.service.tables.getTable('tableName').insert({columnName: value})`

I expected .insert() to return a promise, but it doesn't. In fact, it doesn't seem to return anything at all. But I'd imagine it's asynchronous.

And since it doesn't return a promise, my next bet was that it takes a callback, but when I tried `.insert({columnName: value}, function(r){response.send(r.toString()})`, the entire api just failed to work at all.

How am I supposed to use this .insert function?

And where can I find the documentation to learn this information on my own? Googling is getting me nowhere.

Comment: The answer below contains `.then`, implying that this does return a promise. When you test your code, what does it return? Your existing code does not appear to contain code to capture the promise anyway (though I'm no JS expert). When you tried to use callback what error did you get?

Comment: The answer below does contain `.then`, but it calls different functions. I used `request.service.tables.getTable()` whereas he used `request.azureMobile.tables()`. When I tested the code, I quite naturally had a `.then()` after my `insert`, and in the logs it was saying something like `.then does not exist on unedfined` -- obviously not verbatim, something like that. I was able to determine that `.insert()` was, in fact, returning undefined or null or something like that.

Comment: Just sayin.... complete code samples and complete error messages make these things easier to solve. i.e. a complete repro. (Although I am unlikely to solve this myself someone else might)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [code sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/samples/custom-api-routing/api/category.js#L33) you can use in your Easy API for inserting a record into the table.

```
module.exports = {
    "get": function (req, res, next) {

        req.azureMobile.tables('tableName')
            .insert({columnName: 'value'})
            .then(() => res.status(201).send('Success!'))
            .catch(next);
    }
}
```

The `app.js` file would have the following content.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// This is a base-level Azure Mobile App SDK.
var express = require('express'),
    azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');

// Set up a standard Express app
var app = express();

// If you are producing a combined Web + Mobile app, then you should handle
// anything like logging, registering middleware, etc. here

// Configuration of the Azure Mobile Apps can be done via an object, the
// environment or an auxiliary file.  For more information, see
// http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/global.html#configuration
var mobileApp = azureMobileApps({
    // Explicitly enable the Azure Mobile Apps home page
    homePage: true,
    // Explicitly enable swagger support. UI support is enabled by
    // installing the swagger-ui npm module.
    swagger: true
});

// Import the files from the tables directory to configure the /tables endpoint
mobileApp.tables.import('./tables');

// Import the files from the api directory to configure the /api endpoint
mobileApp.api.import('./api');

// Initialize the database before listening for incoming requests
// The tables.initialize() method does the initialization asynchronously
// and returns a Promise.
mobileApp.tables.initialize()
    .then(function () {
        app.use(mobileApp);    // Register the Azure Mobile Apps middleware
        app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);   // Listen for requests
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this very soon and mark your answer as correct if I get it to work.

Comment: Hmm. Didn't work. Perhaps it's because I made this app-service on an older version of Azure. I checked my app.js file and there's no `require('azure-mobile-apps');`, only `require('azure-mobile-services');` That's ok, I've got my api working via SQL anyway, guess that will have to be good enough. Thanks. [edit] looks like azure-mobile-services is deprecated but I'm not sure how feasible a 'migration' is. Hrm...

Comment: Please don't mark as correct if it doesn't actually work!